# Not sure where margins in bars are coming from in bar chart

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, bar-chart

I have a bar chart that shows four values stacked, and looks like the following:

[image: chart]

In my bar chart, I seem to have some sort of margin in each bar that makes it extend farther than it is supposed to, as can be seen in the console, which states that the purple bar should be 1000 when it's actually a little bit more than that, or as can be seen with the total, which has the same problem. I've confirmed that this is the case by using zero as a value, which still shows a small bar even though it's zero. I want to remove or at least reduce this margin so that my bar graph is a bit more accurate.

Here's the source code:

```
bars
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr("class", "myBars" + function (d) {
        return d.colour;
    })
    .attr({
        height: 30,
        y: 20,
        x: function (d) {
            return barMARGINS.left + d.x;
        },
        width: function (d) {
            return d.value;
        }
    })
```

And here's the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/gamea12/tLrpe3zk/

**EDIT**
[image: chart 2]
Here's an example of when the purple bar should be of length zero.

Comment: Well... isn't it just this: `return barMARGINS.left + d.x;`

Comment: It looks like the issue is actually the text on your axis not lining up correctly with the bar - you can see that the 2000 isn't at the right end. I'd check the width on the bar against the width of the x axis.

Comment: @CoolBlue Yeah, that's the margin that displaces the bars past the axis. What I want to know is why the bars themselves have a thickness that is added to the width. I'll add another picture to illustrate what I mean

Comment: @zacran Actually, I should have mentioned that the scale of the bar graph is the 11/10 of the total, so that there is some white space and also to help illustrate the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `yRange2`to calculate the `width` of the sections, which is defined as follows:

```
yRange2 = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 10])
    .range([barMARGINS.bottom, canvas.height - barMARGINS.top]);
```

note that the `range` does **not** start at 0, thus `yRange2(0) === 10`.

I don't really know why you use this particular scale (and in particular: `barMARGINS.bottom`)

So, you can change the range to something like `.range([0, ...])`, but please note that you then have to change some other margins, etc.

To be honest, you might want to clean up the code a bit so that you don't have the same update function again and again (on the different controls), to make it easier to debug. For the margins, I usually apply a `transform=translate(...)` to the charts/groups, because the scales remain unaffected (I start at 0 and do not have to care about margins).

I hope this helps!

Comment: I had already fixed this my source code to include the update function but forgot to update the link so here's [that](http://jsfiddle.net/gamea12/w87050L4/)

And is there any reason why the range has anything to do with this when all it determines is the length of the bar chart?

Comment: I am not sure I understand - in the example you link, you still have the purple bar, no? Anyway, the scale (linear in your case), maps the domain to the range. So you are using it for the width, hence, if you e.g. have domain (0,1) and range (1,11), you map 0 to 1 or 0.5 to 6. Thus, if the value is 0, you get a positive width, and this seems to be the case here, as `barMARGINS.bottom` is > 0. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I meant that I fixed the messy code, not the problem. I understand what you mean now, but I thought that offsetting the range by the margin is done to avoid it clipping with the axis?

Comment: sorry for the late answer @gamehen, a bit busy these days. I quickly set up an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/chroth/5xp8ker1/ to give an idea how you can define a scale, an axis without mixing the margins into these things. You can see that I just define one axis, one scale and can then easily change margins, etc. Other than that, I can see that you have multiple instances of the same code blocks in your code (or similar ones), this usually a sign that you could potentially improve ('shorten') things with e.g. functions. Don't have time to look into details now, sorry! Hope that hleps!